# Does highcharts supports on blackberry 10?

Tags: highcharts

I have created sample bb10 webworks app which shows charts(pie, line, bar, etc.). I have used highcharts library for the same. Sample charts get displayed on bb10 device but some time graphs not rendered properly. Sometimes graphs are empty.
   In highcharts documentation, they did not mentioned compatibility for Blackberry 10. So I need to know that "does it fully supports on BB10?".

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Full compatibility is available here: http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/compatibility

Comment: Thanks for reply,In compatibility documentation, they did not mentioned anything for Blackberry 10. Does it means highcharts not supported on Blackberry 10?

Comment: BlackBerry is using WebKit as I know, so should work the same way as Chrome or Safari.